# List layer names from Map service using python

Tags: python, arcgis-server, arcgis-10.2, json, arcgis-rest-api

I am trying to get a list of layer names within our rest services for all services and folders. I have two codes that I am trying to put together and for some reason the layer code doesn't seen to work within the Map service code. Any suggestions would be great.
I am running on a 10.2 server.

```
import urllib2, json

server = "hcs084mcgida901"
port = "6080"
baseUrl = "http://gisdev.mcgi.state.mi.us/arcgis/rest/services".format(server, port)

def serviceLayers(URL): 
    fURL = URL + "/" + "?f=json"
    openURL = urllib2.urlopen(fURL, '').read()   
    outJson = json.loads(openURL)   
    return outJson["services"]   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    URL = "http://gisdev.mcgi.state.mi.us/arcgis/rest/services".format(folder)

def getCatalog():
    catalog = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(baseUrl + "/" + "?f=json"))
    print 'ROOT' 
    if "error" in catalog: return
    services = catalog['services']
    for service in services:
    response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(baseUrl + '/' + service['name'] + '/' + service['type'] + "?f=json"))
    print '  %s %s (%s)' % (service['name'], service['type'], 'ERROR' if "error" in response else 'SUCCESS')
    folders = catalog['folders']      
    for folderName in folders:
        catalog = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(baseUrl + "/" + folderName + "?f=json"))
        print folderName
        if "error" in catalog: return
        services = catalog['services']
    for service in services: 
        response = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(baseUrl + '/' + service['name'] + '/' + service['type'] + "?f=json"))
        services = serviceLayers(URL)
    for f in services:   
       print '  %s %s (%s)' % (service['name'], service['type'], 'ERROR' if "error" in response else 'SUCCESS'), "Layer : {}".format(f["name"])   

getCatalog()
```

Comment: "I'am running on a 10.2 server", is this ESRI ArcGIS Server?

Comment: I haven't looked in detail so submitting as a comment not an answer... You have no format codes in your baseURL and URL variables ie `baseUrl = "http://gisdev.mcgi.state.mi.us/arcgis/rest/services".format(server, port)`

Comment: Yes it is an ESRI ArcGIS Server. I can get both codes to run independently but getting them to cooperate together is the issue I'm having

Comment: Hope you have looked into http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=12dde73e0e784e47818162b4d41ee340, nice tools to get started working with map services (Python source code included).

Answer (score 5):

I use [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) to do stuff like this:

```
import requests

def _post(service, _params={'f': 'pjson'}, ret_json=True):
    """Post Request to REST Endpoint

    Required:
    service -- full path to REST endpoint of service

    Optional:
    _params -- parameters for posting a request
    ret_json -- return the response as JSON.  Default is True.
    """
    r = requests.post(service, params=_params, verify=False)

    # make sure return
    if r.status_code != 200:
        raise NameError('"{0}" service not found!\n{1}'.format(service, r.raise_for_status()))
    else:
        if ret_json:
            return r.json()
        else:
            return r

def list_services(service='http://server.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services'):
    """returns a list of all services

    Optional:
    service -- full path to a rest service
    """
    all_services = []
    r = _post(service)
    for s in r['services']:
        all_services.append('/'.join([service, s['name'], s['type']]))
    for s in r['folders']:
        new = '/'.join([service, s])
        endpt = _post(new)
        for serv in endpt['services']:
           all_services.append('/'.join([service, serv['name'], serv['type']]))
    return all_services

def list_layers(service):
    """lists all layers in a mapservice

    Returns a list of field objects with the following properties:
        name -- name of layer
        id -- layer id (int)
        minScale -- minimum scale range at which layer draws
        maxScale -- maximum scale range at which layer draws
        defaultVisiblity -- the layer is visible (bool)
        parentLayerId -- layer id of parent layer if in group layer (int)
        subLayerIds -- list of id's of all child layers if group layer (list of int's)

    Required:
    service -- full path to mapservice
    """
    r = _post(service)
    if 'layers' in r:
        return [layer(p) for p in r['layers']]
    return

def list_tables(service):
    """List all tables in a MapService"""
    r = _post(service)
    if 'tables' in r:
        return [table(p) for p in r['tables']]
    return None

class layer:
    """class to handle layer info"""
    def __init__(self, lyr_dict):
        for key, value in lyr_dict.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

class table:
    """class to handle table info"""
    def __init__(self, tab_dict):
        for key, value in tab_dict.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)

if __name__ == '__main__':

    for serv in list_services():
        print serv
        print 'Layers:\n'
        for lyr in [l.name for l in list_layers(serv)]:
            print lyr
        print '\n\n'
```

Comment: I don't have Request downloaded to run that code. What steps do you recommend to get that to work with python?

Comment: The above code is in Python and requests is a module.  All you need to do is download the requests module.  There is an install executable from the unofficial binary python packages web page.  This will automatically put the requests module in your PYTHONPATH.  http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Got the request to work thanks. Although now when running through the script I am getting this error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
File "d:\Tools\test1.py", line 85, in <module>
  for lyr in [l.name for l in list_layers(serv)]:

Comment: Hmm, that is strange.  I would maybe throw a try/except block in for the list layers part under the if __name__ == '__main__'. None is returned if there are no layers in the map service (or perhaps if there is an error).  It may be be better to change the default return to an empty list [] so that it is still an iterable and will not bomb out.

Comment: Avoiding certificate check may prevent from access or at least mangled response!